# QSS1 for ODE systems

Tags: ode, numerical-integration

do you know any python library to handle systems of ode with quantized state method?
I'm trying t figure out what do you have to do after you quantized the x(t) into q(t).

Edit:
I wrote this code, is it doing what is intended to? Note that it's trying to solve the following ivp:

dx_dt = cos(x)
x(0)=0

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class QSS1Solver:
    @staticmethod
    def qss1_ivp(ode, x0, h, t_target):
        x_values = [x0]
        x = x0
        t = 0.0
        slope_n = 0
        slope_o = 0

        
        while t < t_target:
            slope_o = slope_n
            slope_n = ode(t)
            print(slope_n)
            
            # Quantize the slope to control the change
            epsilon = 0.60  # Small value for quantization
            if abs(slope_n) < epsilon:
                slope = 0
                x_values.append(x_values[-1])  # Append the new value
            else:
                slope = slope_n
                x += h * slope  # Update using the quantized slope
                x_values.append(x)  # Append the new value
                        
            t += h  # Increment time by step size
        
        return x_values

def ode_equation(x):
    return math.cos(x)

def analytical_solution(x):
    return math.sin(x)

# Initial conditions
x0 = 0.0
h = 0.1
t_target = 10.0  # Target time

solver = QSS1Solver()
x_values_qss1 = solver.qss1_ivp(ode_equation, x0, h, t_target)

# Plotting the numerical solution
time_points_qss1 = [i * h for i in range(len(x_values_qss1))]

plt.plot(time_points_qss1, x_values_qss1, label='Numerical (QSS1)')

# Calculating and plotting the analytical solution
x_analytical = [analytical_solution(i * h) for i in range(len(x_values_qss1))]
plt.plot(time_points_qss1, x_analytical, label='Analytical')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('x')
plt.title('Comparison of Numerical (QSS1) and Analytical Solutions')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: So this is essentially the Euler method, only that the time step is computed from the derivative vector as `dt = min(dQ[k]/abs(F[k]))`, where `F = f(q(t),t)`. Or perhaps that is only true for the autonomous case.

Comment: @LutzLehmann could you please be more explicit regarding the parameters you are introducing?

also could you point me to an already implemented script that implement qss1 (or higher order methods)?

Comment: `dQ` is the cell or quantum size vector, in a normal solver this would be the absolute tolerance vector. I also just read the wikipedia page on this, the ODE is `x'=f(x,t)` and the Euler step is `x_next = x+F*dt`. Essentially you build a box around the current point, follow the line `(t+s, x+F*s)` until it reaches the boundaries of the box and evaluate the direction vector `F` at this new point. In writing this, most adaptive-step methods should give a similar result.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I feel like I'm an idiot: I edited the question with some code, can you give it a glance? QSS seems super interesting, still incredibly hard to grasp correctly

Comment: No, your current version is just a fixed-step method with a slightly modified ODE function. For the method in question you want a bound on the step in space, not in time.